# How To Program Repetitive Actions on Desktop Applications?

Tags: windows-10, automation, programming

I have to do repetitive actions like croping segments from images.

I do it quite well with "Windows capture screen" + MC Paint, but I believe that it can be automated. I have no idea how to do that with, for example, Python. I think it can be easily done with some "actions recording" For example, I do actions by myself (like scrolling, selecting with the mouse, striking 'ctrl + s', 'enter') and all these actions are recorded and then it will be reproduced by some kind of bot.

So, is there some software for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and it has worked miracles.  It won't be able to recognize something on a screen, but it will move your mouse, click, input with keyboard and more.

It is a command line utility, so you will have to make a batch script to automate tasks, but it isn't hard to learn how to do.

If you ever get stuck or need help on how to use it, just let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of software is known as Macro Recorders. For example, https://www.macrorecorder.com/